# What is the best way to build a one-to-many relationship?

Tags: objective-c, performance, algorithm

I have an array of `Videos` objects with, among other things, the properties `id` and `tags`.

I want to build a dictionary whose `key` is a `tag` and whose `value` is an array of `id`'s.

For example, some `Video` objects might look like this:

`Video{ id:1, tags:[funny,political,humor] }`

`Video{ id:2, tags:[political,america] }`

I want the result dictionary to look like this:

`VideosWithTags["funny":[1]; "political":[1,2]; "humor":[1]; "america":[2]]`

Is there a standard algorithm to accomplish this?

Currently I'm doing something like this:

```c
for (NSDictionary *video in videos)
{
    NSNumber *videoId = [video objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSArray *tags = [video objectForKey:@"tags"];

    for (NSString *tag in tags)
    {
        NSMutableArray *videoIdsForTag = nil;

        if ([videosAndTags objectForKey:tag] != nil) //same tag with videoIds already exists
        {
            videoIdsForTag = [videosAndTags objectForKey:tag];
            [videoIdsForTag addObject:videoId];

            //add the updated array to the tag key
            [videosAndTags setValue:videoIdsForTag forKey:tag];
        }
        else //tag doesn't exist yet, create it and add the videoId to a new array
        {
            NSMutableArray *videoIds = [NSMutableArray array];
            [videoIds addObject:videoId];

            //add the new array to the tag key
            [videosAndTags setObject:videoIds forKey:tag];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That code looks perfectly reasonable to me.  Is there something about it that you think needs improving?  It would be easy to refactor it to make it a little bit shorter, but it wouldn't change the performance appreciably.

Comment: Not particularly, more curious than anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this look a little cleaner by using the new literal syntax.

I think you could benefit by making your `if` branches do less work. e.g. You would be better of trying to retrieve the `videoIds` array then if it doesn't exist - create it and add it to the `videosAndTags` object and then the code after this point can be consistent with no duplication of logic

```
for (NSDictionary *video in videos) {
  NSNumber *videoId = video[@"id"];
  NSArray  *tags    = video[@"tags"];

  for (NSString *tag in tags) {
    NSMutableArray *videoIds = videosAndTags[tag];
    if (!videoIds) {
      videoIds = [NSMutableArray array];
      videosAndTags[tag] = videoIds;
    }

    // This is the only line where I manipulate the array
    [videoIds addObject:videoId]; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice. This is what I'm looking for. Didn't know about those literals!

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray* videos =
    @[@{ @"id" : @1, @"tags" : @[ @"funny", @"political", @"humor" ] },
      @{ @"id" : @2, @"tags" : @[ @"political", @"america" ] } ];
NSMutableDictionary* videosAndTags = [NSMutableDictionary new];

// find distinct union of tags
NSArray* tags = [videos valueForKeyPath: @"@distinctUnionOfArrays.tags"];

// for each unique tag
for( NSString* tag in tags )
{
    // filter array so we only have ones that have the right tag
    NSPredicate* p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"tags contains %@", tag];
    videosAndTags[ tag ] = [[videos filteredArrayUsingPredicate: p] valueForKeyPath: @"id"];
}
```

Here is another approach using NSPredicate and valueForKeyPath.

I don't used them often, but sometimes they can prove to be useful.

(I think they call this the Functional Programming style of things, but I am not so sure)

[NSPredicate reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html)
[Key Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html)